# I don't understand why the swiper script don't work

Tags: javascript, html

thanks for the help. I can't understand why the script don't work.
It's my first time in using Swiper.

```
<div class="home" id="home">
        <div class="swiper homeSlider">
            <div class="swiper-warpper warpper">
                <div class="swiper-slide slide slide1">
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="#" alt="#">
                        <h3>Ipsum latum</h3>
                        <h1>Ipsum latum</h1>
                        <p>ispum latum</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Réserver</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide slide slide2">
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="#" alt="#">
                        <h3>RACLETTE</h3>
                        <h1>Plat savoyard</h1>
                        <p>Venez goûter ce plat typique de la Savoie</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Réserver</a>
                    </div>
                </div>    
                <div class="swiper-slide slide slide3">
                    <div class="content">
                            <img src="#" alt="#">
                            <h3>RACLETTE</h3>
                            <h1>Plat savoyard</h1>
                            <p>Venez goûter ce plat typique de la Savoie</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn">Réserver</a>
                    </div>
                </div>        
                        
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
   
   <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper(".homeSlider", {
      spaceBetween: 30,
      centeredSlides: true,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 7500,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
      },
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true,
      },
      loop: true,
    }); 
  </script> 
    
   
</body>
</html>
```

I try to change class name or take the script src at the begining.
I watched lot of video on Youtube, review my code, search on the internet but nothing work.

Comment: There is one typo in class name: <div class="swiper-wrapper">. It works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SwiperJS required your HTML structure to follow the [minimal layout](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#swiper-full-html-layout).

You'll need to mimic those classes, your issue is caused by:

```html
<div class="swiper-warpper warpper">
```

That needs to be

```html
<div class="swiper-wrapper warpper">
```

---

Demo snippet:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".homeSlider", {
    spaceBetween: 30,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
    loop: true,
});
```

```css
.home, .swiper-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/9.1.0/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="home" id="home">
    <div class="swiper homeSlider">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper warpper">
            <div class="swiper-slide slide slide1">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="#" alt="#">
                    <h3>Ipsum latum</h3>
                    <h1>Ipsum latum</h1>
                    <p>ispum latum</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Réserver</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide slide slide2">
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="#" alt="#">
                    <h3>RACLETTE</h3>
                    <h1>Plat savoyard</h1>
                    <p>Venez goûter ce plat typique de la Savoie</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Réserver</a>
                </div>
            </div>    
            <div class="swiper-slide slide slide3">
                <div class="content">
                        <img src="#" alt="#">
                        <h3>RACLETTE</h3>
                        <h1>Plat savoyard</h1>
                        <p>Venez goûter ce plat typique de la Savoie</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Réserver</a>
                </div>
            </div>        

        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```